# Link to web without WebView and Url_launcher

Tags: flutter, dart

Please tell me how to put a link to a web page without WebView and Url_launcher.
I need to link to the ElevatedButton. Isn't there a simpler way than WebView and Url_launcher?

I'm trying to launch Url_launcher.

Changed the post. Posted the full code. There are no errors, nothing happens when the button is clicked.

```
import 'package:australia/testPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:australia/qlist.dart';
import 'package:australia/testResult.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Mainpage(),
    ),
  );
}

class Mainpage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Mainpage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 1"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Image.asset("assets/images/kangaroo2.png"),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "1",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          wordSpacing: 2),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "2",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          wordSpacing: 2),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "3",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          wordSpacing: 2),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return MyHomePage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: const Size(350, 50),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              child: Text(
                "Exam Test",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return MyHomePage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: const Size(350, 50),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              child: Text(
                "Learn questions",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                const url = 'https://google.com';
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: const Size(350, 50),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              child: Text(
                "Common Bond booklet",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the simpler way you're looking for is by using packages, which are url_launcher and webView, rather than trying to find alternatives (that are simpler it don't exist), it's better to drop the main issue that you faced with them, so the community can help.

Comment: Already spent half a day on url_Launcher but it still does not want to work.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work, it's configuration on some platform, or the package itself or what ?

Comment: Changed the post. Posted the full code. There are no errors, nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: this is because nothing wrong happens in your code, the url_launcher package offers a method for launching URLs, which is launchUrl(), I assume that you expected https://google.com to be launched, but what you did is just declare a variable with, I guess it's a good start to read the documentation of the package https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: because it requires also some configurations to make to your project before using it.

Comment: I would like to. But so far it doesn't work.)